# Como puedo insertar una variable JS dentro de una consulta PHP

Tags: sql

necesito insertar el valor que tengo en la variable **selectedOption** en la consulta donde dice **VARIABLE_JS** pero no se como me pueden ayudar?

```
var selectedOption = $(this).val();
        var html = '';
        html += "@php
        $datas = DB::table('ciudades_activities')->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total_user, ciudades.name'))
                ->join('ciudades', 'ciudades.id', '=', 'ciudades_activities.ciudades_id')
                ->join('registers_eventos', 'registers_eventos.ciudades_activities_id', '=', 'ciudades_activities.id')
                ->join('semanas_activities', 'ciudades_activities.activities_id', '=', 'semanas_activities.activities_id')
                ->join('activities', 'activities.id', '=', 'semanas_activities.activities_id')
                ->where('activities.types_eventos_id', 1)
                ->where('semanas_activities.semanas_id', 'VARIABLE_JS')
                ->groupBy('ciudades.name')
                ->get();
        @endphp";
        html += "@foreach($datas as $data)";
        html += "<div class='col text-center'>";
        html += "<h2 class='nombre_panel' >{{$data->name}}</h2>";
        html +="<h2 class='nombre_panel' >{{$data->total_user}}</h2>";
        html +="<h2 class='nombre_panel' ></h2>";
        html += "</div>";
        html +="@endforeach";
```

Comment: Para pasar valores desde el cliente (Javascript) al servidor (PHP) se suele usar Ajax o la  nueva API Fetch de Javascript. De este modo, pasas el valor, procesas los datos y los devuelves al cliente, pudiendo actualizar el contenido de la página sin necesidad de recargarla. Si no usas Ajax o Fetch, tendrás que pasar los datos mediante los métodos GET o POST, recargar la página y en PHP recoger el dato buscándolo en la super global. Ajax y luego Fetch, vinieron para hacer todo ese proceso mucho más simple y más elegante (no necesidad de recarga cada vez que pasas un dato).

Comment: Y si seperas el Backend del Frontend? Bueno es que en lo personal siempre hago un formulario con html, cacho las variables con JS  y las mando a PHP por post o Get, pero siempre en hojas diferentes para poder tener una mejor dinamica,

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de lo que quiza te puede ayudar mas, con mi ejemplo de un buscador predictivo

Este seria el HTML

```
<div class="container">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lista" id="lista" placeholder="Buscar">

<span id="lista_oculta" style="display: none;" >
<select multiple class='form-control' style="display: none;" id='id_performas'>
</select>
</span>

</div>

<div id="respuesta_busqueda" ></div>
```

Este seria el JS

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#lista').on('keyup',function(){
        var esc = $('#lista').val();
        if ( esc !='') {
            $.post("php/consulta_dat.php",{data_lista:esc},function(){
            }).done(function(respuesta){
                $('#lista_oculta').show();
                $('#id_performas').show();
                $('#id_performas').html(respuesta);
              
            })
        } else {
            $('#lista_oculta').hide();
            $('#id_performas').hide();
            $('#respuesta_busqueda').hide();
        }
      
    })
    // $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_performas').change(function(){
      $('#id_performas option:selected').each(function(){
          var option = $(this).val();
         // alert(option)
          $.post('php/consulta_dat.php',{buscar_data:option},function(){
          }).done(function(data){
              $('#lista_oculta').hide();
              //console.log(data)
              $('#respuesta_busqueda').show();
               $('#respuesta_busqueda').html(data)
          })
      })
    })
    $('#body_cer').on('click',function(){        
            $('#lista_oculta').hide(200);
    })
})

 
 </script>
```

Este seria el PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['data_lista'])) {
  $escritura = $_POST['data_lista'];
  include_once "ConsultaADR.php";
  $cons = new ConsultaInfoADR();
  $data = $cons->Consulta_COUNC_NOMBRE_Exist($escritura);
  if (isset($data)) {
      for ($i=0; $i <count($data) ; $i++) {
          echo"<option value='".$data[$i]['id_empleado_plant']."' >".$data[$i]['nombre_s']." ".$data[$i]['apellido_p']." ".$data[$i]['apellido_m']."</option>";
      }
  }
}
 if (isset($_POST['buscar_data'])) {
  $escritura = $_POST['buscar_data'];
  include_once "ConsultaADR.php";
  $cons = new ConsultaInfoADR();
  $data = $cons->info_datos_us($escritura);
  if (isset($data)) {
    echo"
    <table class='table'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope='col'>#</th>
        <th scope='col'>First</th>
        <th scope='col'>Last</th>
        <th scope='col'>Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";
    $a =1;
  for ($i=0; $i < count($data) ; $i++) { 
        echo" <tr>
        <th scope='row'>".$a."</th>
        <td>".$data[$i]['nombre_empleado']."</td>
        <td>".$data[$i]['nombre_puesto_adr']."</td>
        <td>".$data[$i]['nombre_puesto']."</td>
      </tr>";
  }
    
     
  echo"</tbody>
  </table>
  
  
  ";
  } else {
    echo"No hay nada de este empleado";
  }
  

  

}
?>
```